# if user has above 10,000 points they get level 5 , but they get level1? mysql logic error?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a weird problem with my mysql query syntax.
I have made a system by which shows specific ranking to a user when they have certain amount of points.

For example
when they have 1000 or more points , they are level 1
3000 or more points , they are level 2
5000 or more points , they are level 3
8000 or more points , they are level 4
9000 or more points , they are level 5

Mysql table structure:
Table name: rank
structure: pts , rankname

mysql query as follows:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rank WHERE pts <= '$userpts' ORDER BY pts DESC LIMIT 1")
or die(mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if($row){
  $rank = $row['rankname'];
  echo $rank;
}
```

However a weird problem occurred, when a user points exceeds 10,000 points , they should get the rankname level 5 **but instead they get the rankname level 1** (which user between 1000-2999 points gets)
Not sure what's happening , they should get exactly level 5.
(P/S when user has 8500 points they get level 4 which means points below 10k works fine to get the ranknames)

Anything wrong with my query logic?
Im confused myself.

Comment: how are you updating the value of rank when a user gains points?

Comment: Can you show us the complete table structure with data types? Currently you are only showing column names. It might be that there is some string sorting and not numeric sorting going on. HOwever without the complete table definition I cant say.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that the `pts` field is a [number field](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html), *not*  a CHAR or VARCHAR field.

10000 as a number is larger than both 1000 and 9000. Strings, however, are compared according to their lexicographical sorting order (i.e., alphabetically), so then you get this order:

```
1000
10000
9000
```

Comment: yes thats it , thanks , i accidentally set it as varchar , just changed to int and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Your column is a text datatype (e.g. VARCHAR) instead of a number.

Answer (score 0):

To start, if you're using a field in a numeric comparison as you are with pts (<=), don't compare it to a string. Remove the quotes from around $userpts.

Also, embedding PHP variables directly into an SQL statement could make you vulnerable to SQL injection (depending on the rest of your code).

Comment: It doesn't matter if the quotes are there even when comparing numerals.

Comment: Ok, I'll buy that. I'd still remove them for clarity.